# Rust testing cargo test --verbose does not show ouptut?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

If I create the function

```rust
#[test]
fn foo () {
  dbg!("BAR");
  println!("BAZ");
  assert!(true);
}
```

And I run `cargo test -v` or `cargo test --verbose` I can confirm the test ran, but no output is shown. The words "BAR" and "BAZ" do not exist in the output.

When I read `cargo test --help`, I see different options than in `cargo --help`: it documents a `-vv` option. But I don't see a difference with `cargo --verbose test -vv`, nor `cargo test -vv`.

---

I'm using cargo 1.63.0-nightly (4d92f07f3 2022-06-09)

Comment: If you post a self-answered question, _at least ensure it is not a duplicate_.

Answer (score 0):

## `--nocapture`

The right invocation here is

```
cargo test -- --nocapture
```

[From the docs,](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html)

> By default the Rust test harness hides output from test execution to keep results readable. Test output can be recovered (e.g., for debugging) by passing `--nocapture` to the test binaries:
>
> ```
> cargo test -- --nocapture
> ```

---

I've opened [Issue #10777 on GitHub to suggest changing this behavior](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/10777#issue-1277499859)